# Add a string at the end of url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have various links on the site and would like to add a certain string at the end of each url that has a domain example.com inside the url. For example: all url's with domain example.com would have a string at the end "mystring", so the complete url would be: `example.com?mystring`. I'm trying to acomplish this so i can generate keybuilder string at the end of urls.

Sample html structure: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/385fe32m/)

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below

```
$(function(){
  //iterate all a tag having href="example.com"
  $('ul li a[href="example.com"]').each(function(){
    //set href with new value
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href')+'?myString');
  });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/385fe32m/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/385fe32m/4/):**

```
$('ul li a').click(function(){
   var domain=$(this).attr('href');
   alert(domain+'?myString');
});
```

Comment: I have links also outside the ul.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use below code :

```
$('a[href^="example.com"]').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', href + '?myString');
});
```

Comment: Wish i could mark multiple correct answers, thank you, works well also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to get all anchors which contain `example.com`, then just set the `href`:

```
$('a[href*="example.com"]').prop('href', function() {
   return this.href + '?yourString'; 
});
```